# How to add extra packages to Ubuntu install CD using kickstart

Tags: linux, installation, ubuntu-12.04, packages, kickstart

I used kickstart to automate Ubuntu12.04 alternate iso installation. I am able to automate the installation. Now I want to install some extra packages such as teamviewer during OS installation. But the problem is that it cannot be installed online. I want to add these packages to install CD and install those packages during installation itself.

Does anyone know how to do this?Any help is appreciated.

Note:Is it possible to extract `initd.gz`, add the packages and again compress it, so that after installation, I can install it by specifying the path.

Answer (score 0):

In **%post** section you can do all your commands, like if you did them in terminal. So it should look like this (example):

```
%post
mount -t iso9660 -o ro /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom #Mount CDROM
cd /cdrom
dpkg -i virtualbox.deb #Install your package
%end
```

Reference:

> http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mounting-cdrom-in-linux
>
> http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/dpkg.1.html